# Jquery capture tab + some key combination

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I catch, for example, `tab+t` combination with jQuery? I've found a lot of examples with `alt`, `shift` and `ctrl`, since event object contains special flags in order to understand if, for example, alt was pressed. But there is not such thing for tab.

Comment: Actually I want to make some hotkeys. I took the idea from asana.com, where they chose tab keys for shortcuts, seems like they're safe to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. It's a bit convoluted and there is likely an easier way, but it works fine.

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/spybhhxc/

```
var tabdown = false;
var tdown = false;

$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 9) {
        tabdown = true;
    }
    if(e.which === 84)
    {
        tdown = true;
    }
    if(tabdown && tdown)
    {
        //do your thing
    }
});

$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 9) {
        tabdown = false;
    }
    if(e.which === 84)
    {
        tdown = false;
    }
});
```

This presents a problem though, as once you press tab, the document is unfocused as the tab key navigates to elements in a browser. You would be much better off using something like `alt` or `ctrl` which don't interact with the browser.

Answer (score 0):

We can have a tab key pressed [tabPressed] variable which will be set to true on key down and unset the same on its key up event. We will using the tab key pressed[tabPressed] variable to check whether it is in pressed state during the other key press activities. The tab keycode is 9.

jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/e3Lveyj2/

```
 var tabPressed=false;
 function handleKeyDown(e) {
 var evt = (e==null ? event:e);
 if(evt.keyCode == 9){
    tabPressed=true;
}
 if ((tabPressed) && (evt.keyCode == 84))  { 
    alert ("You pressed 'Tab+t'")
}
}



function handleKeyUp(e) {
 var evt = (e==null ? event:e);

 if(evt.keyCode == 9){
    tabPressed=false;
}
}
document.onkeydown = handleKeyDown;
document.onkeyup = handleKeyUp;
```